# Which Yodlee API should I use to download users transactions?

Tags: yodlee

I'm confused about Yodlee REST API. There are:

- "API" [ https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API ]
- "Aggregation API" [ https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API ]

Which should I use to download users transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the APIs obtain user transactions. The new Envestnet | Yodlee API is our new aggregation API which has a more simplified data model and simpler implementation. I highly recommend you use the new Yodlee APIs.  Also, check out our [Video Tutorials](http://bit.ly/YodleeU).